Association rule on incident/event relations in Python
I have two sets of data : a list of events and a list of solved incidents with the event that caused each of them. How can I train a model to predict which event caused a new incident to occur?
For example by using these :
List of solved training Incidents :



N°
Service source
Client Source
...
Event source




1
Service A
HR Team
...
A345


2
Service B
DevTeam
...
B678


3
Service A
External
...
C901



List of training Events :



N°
Target service
Change Effected
Developper
...




A345
Service A
Function refactoring
Mike I
...


U567
Service C
Function deprecation
Mike I
...


B678
Service B
Bug Fixing
John D
...


T234
Service A
Function refactoring
Dave L
...


C901
Service A
Function deprecation
Dave L
...


V890
Service B
Bug Fixing
Mike I
...



I now want the model to predict the source of this Incident :



N°
Service source
Client Source
...
Event source




4
Service C
External
...




From this list of Events :



N°
Target service
Change Effected
Developper
...




R123
Service A
Function refactoring
Mike I
...


S456
Service C
Function deprecation
Mike I
...


T789
Service C
Bug Fixing
John D
...




Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
